# finding the value of child nodes in a table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
$('#Row1').html() = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  /></td>'+
                    '<td>One</td>'+
                    '<td>Two</td>'+
    '<td>Three</td>'+
    '<td>Four</td>'+
    '<td>Five</td>'+
    '<td>Six</td>'+
    '<td>Seven</td>'+
    '<td>Eight</td>'+
    '<td>Nine</td>'+                
    </tr>';
```

I want to access all of the values apart from the 1st cell.
I can access using `$('#Row1').children().siblings().next().html()` and so on adding a `next()` each time.

Is there a more efficient way to do this in case of a large number of cells.

Comment: That is not how .html() works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/dr2cs/2/**

```
 $(document).on('click','.check',function(e) {
     if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#Row1').find('td:gt(0)').each(function(){
             $('#values').append($(this).text()+'<br />');
         })
     } })

 var domnode = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /></td>'+
                     '<td>One</td>'+
                     '<td>Two</td>'+
     '<td>Three</td>'+
     '<td>Four</td>'+
     '<td>Five</td>'+
     '<td>Six</td>'+
     '<td>Seven</td>'+
     '<td>Eight</td>'+
     '<td>Nine</td>'+                
     '</tr>'; $('#Row1').html(domnode);
```

try something like this ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of, html work like that :

```
$('#Row1').html('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  /></td>'+
                '<td>One</td>'+
                '<td>Two</td>'+
'<td>Three</td>'+
'<td>Four</td>'+
'<td>Five</td>'+
'<td>Six</td>'+
'<td>Seven</td>'+
'<td>Eight</td>'+
'<td>Nine</td>'+                
'</tr>');
```

i.e : it is a function.

Then, to answer your question, you can use `.not()`:

```
$('#Row1').children().not(':first').html();
```

But then, children select the `tr`. So you actually want :

```
$('#Row1').find('td').not(':first').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use

```
$('#Row1').html('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  /></td>'+
    '<td>One</td>'+
    '<td>Two</td>'+
    '<td>Three</td>'+
    '<td>Four</td>'+
    '<td>Five</td>'+
    '<td>Six</td>'+
    '<td>Seven</td>'+
    '<td>Eight</td>'+
    '<td>Nine</td>'+                
    '</tr>');
```

To access all cells expect the first you can do

```
 $("#Row1 td:not(:first)").each(function(){

        console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example of adding the row is wrong. You would not add `<tr>` to the rows html.

You can use [`:gt()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$("#Row1 td:gt(0)")
```

or

```
$("#Row1").find("td:gt(0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single selector with no further traversal you could do this:

`$('#Row1 tr td:not(tr td:first)');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index based selector `:gt(0)` to get the cells then use `each()` to iterate over them:

```
$('#Row1 td:gt(0)').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html())
});
```

[DOCUMENTATION: INDEX SELECTOR](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

[DOCUMENTATION: EACH()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)